# 1993 B.Efron & R. Tibshirani Exercise 9.1 on standard deviation of the mean

Tags: linear-model, standard-deviation, standard-error

I am stuck in the exercise 9.3 in the book "An Introduction to the Bootsrap" of Bradley Efron and Robert J. Tibshirani published in 1993. Here is the exercise statement:

"Show that formula (9.17) gives formula (5.4) for the standard error of the mean."

The formula (9.17) is the following:
$$
se(\hat{\beta_j}) = \sigma_F \sqrt{G^{jj}} \ \ \ (9.17).
$$

The formula is part of the study of linear models. $se(\cdot)$ is the standard error. Just to agree on the terms, here we supposed that we observe variables $(C_1,Y_1),\cdots, (C_n,Y_n)$ for $C_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and we want to find a relationship of the form
$$
y_i = C_i^t\beta + \epsilon_i,
$$
where $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p$ is the parameter of interest and $\epsilon_i$ is the error term with standard deviation $\sigma_F$.

On the other hand, (5.4) is simply
$$
se(\bar{X}) = \sigma_F/\sqrt{n}.
$$
where $\bar{X}$ is the mean of $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ that are iid normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma_F$.

I do not really understand where to start and how to link these two formulas. I am not sure to understand what it is asked. Any help or hint(preferred) is welcome.

Comment: if you have an intercept only model, what does the intercept equal?

Comment: ah I see, it was just this, thanks a lot!